# Remove Event Listener of Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

How do I remove the event listener, so the alert box will not be popped up anymore after `Remove Listener to prevent it from triggering pop_up` button is clicked?

```js
document.querySelector('#hihi-toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  alert("I am Jim")
});

function remove_event_listener_button() {
  //document.querySelector('#hihi-toggle').removeEventListener()
}
```

```html
<button id="hihi-toggle" data-enabled="false">Alert Box </button>
<button onclick="remove_event_listener_button()">Remove Listener to prevent it from triggering pop_up</button>
```

Comment: Why not use the enabled attribute?
`const hihi = document.getElementById('hihi');
    hihi.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const enabled = e.target.dataset.enabled === "true";
      if (enabled) alert("I am Jim");
    });

    document.getElementById('hihi-toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
      const enabled = hihi.dataset.enabled === "true";
      hihi.dataset.enabled = !enabled;
    });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const eventHandler = e => alert("I am Jim");

document.querySelector('#hihi-toggle').addEventListener('click', eventHandler);

function remove_event_listener_button() {
  document.querySelector('#hihi-toggle').removeEventListener('click',eventHandler)
}
```

Comment: That won't work. The function you are trying to remove from the event listener isn't the same function that you added (even if it is identical).

Comment: It does not work, unfortunately :)

Comment: Try the fixed version. I had a brainfart there, sorry